# Hide Header Components from Individual Web Pages in Dynamics Portal

Tags: html, css, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have a website where I would like to hide some components on the home page. I have a header template which is referenced in the all the pages in the website, includes a search menu. I would like to hide that search option from the header on the home page.
I see many options to hide the headers all together, but not for individual components within the header.
Can someone help me with this.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `display: none;` in CSS?

See: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: I tried this. This would hide the component across the website.